# Appcelerator - Android multiline label

Tags: label, row, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I need, into a TableViewRow, to have a two lines label but the label only shows one line.

This is my code:

**1. tss file**

```
"#titulo[platform=android] ":{
    font:{fontSize:15},
    textAlign:'left',
    color: '#0a80b0',
    top: 2,
    left:45,
    height:40,
    ellipsize: true,
    wordWrap: false,
    lines: 2
}
```

**2. js controller file**

```
var labelWidth =  Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth - 45 - 20;

$.titulo.setText(args.get('title'));
$.titulo.setWidth(labelWidth);
```

Thank you for advance.

Question in appcelerator Q&A: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/183058/android--multiline-text-label-into-a-table-row

**EDIT:**

Now I have two lines, but the last word of my first line is cut...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use this instead:

```
"#titulo[platform=android] ":{
    font:{fontSize:15},
    textAlign:'left',
    color: '#0a80b0',
    top: 2,
    left:45,
    height:40,
    // ellipsize: true,
    wordWrap: true,
    // lines: 2
}
```

This will make the text wrap as long as the height has room for it.

Comment: Then it needs 3 lines and you should increase the height (or set it to `Ti.UI.SIZE`)

Comment: I want to lines, that's ok, but the last word in the first line is cut.... Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: See the image above, please

Comment: What's that last word? It does not fit?

Comment: The last word is "ecológico" and the line ends in "eco", I don't understand what is happening

Comment: What if you replace ó by o? Maybe when it counts character length it decides not to wrap but then does ellipsize somehow.

Comment: To resolve this, at the end, I have changed the structure of my row. I have done an horizontal layout (image | view | image) and into the middle view I have used vertical layout with the two labels. It's the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is a new property in SDK 4.1.0.GA or later. Do you use that version or an older?

Comment: No, I'm using 3.5.0.GA

Comment: It's not available before 4.1.0.GA to force a min/max nr of lines. The number of lines will depend on the height you set to the label or the length of the text if you set no (or `Ti.UI.SIZE`) height and do not disable wordwrap. This sample app shows that it does work with 4.1.0.GA: https://github.com/appcelerator-developer-relations/appc-sample-ti410

Comment: Max number of lines is not important for me, I need that the label respect their width and write in a new line if her height allows it

Comment: That's what it does by default.